# Where to go to see an exception thrown by a browser based java app

Tags: firefox, browser, java, debug, exceptions

I have a java app that is running in my browser.  At a specific point the app will crash.  I would like to find the exception that is being thrown (if possible) so I can show it to the support of the company that makes the app.

Is there a standard place for this?  Or a way that capture it?  (So I can prove that it is happening.)

I am using Firefox, but could use IE if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In Firefox, go to the Tool menu. It should have a Java Console item if you have installed the extension [Java Console 6.0.02.03](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5403).

If you use the Web Developer extension, CTRL+SHIFT+O will also open the Java Console.

On Windows, when Java is running, there is also a Java icon in the System Tray, near the clock. Right-click on it, and you should find an entry "Open the console" (with the version of the JRE).

[image]

Comment: I tried to install this and after the installation and restart of Firefox a popup said that Java Console was no longer supported and would be removed on the next install.  I tried running it anyway and it would not start.